# Button border radius in jQuery mobile 1.4.0

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-button

I have the following button in my jQuery mobile 1.4.0 , I want to modify its border radius in order to be as the button in the following image , I have tried the following code but it didn't work for me , How can i modify the button border radius in jQuery mobile 1.4.0? Plese help me ..

```
<div   class="ui-btn ui-input-btn  center_BTN " >                                                   
<input type="button" id="save" data-inline="true" value=" Save"  data-icon="check"      />

</div>
```

CSS

```
.center_BTN {
  text-align:center;
  background-color:transparent !important;
  border:none;
}


.center_BTN.ui-btn,.center_BTN .ui-input-btn{

  border: solid #cccccc 5px;
  border-radius:32px !important;

}
```

[image]

Comment: you cant do it with CSS as jQM wraps input in a div. you can do it this way http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/mHy3j/

Comment: @OmarThank you very very much, Can you Post your answer so i can accept it .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update

jQM has added a new feature which doesn't require any JS intervention. Create a custom class e.g. `foo` and then add `data-wrapper-class="foo"` attribute to `input` itself.

```
<input type="button" data-wrapper-class="foo" />
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/b2pP2/)**

---

### Old answer

jQuery Mobile dynamically wraps `input` in a div where all CSS styles are added to it, hence it is not possible to style it *statically*.

Create a custom class with all your CSS and add it after page is created.

```
$(".selector").closest("div").addClass("custom-class");
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/mHy3j/)**

Answer (score 0):

Rounded rectangle button

```
.ui-btn-corner-all {
   border-radius: 1m;
}
```

Rectangle button

```
.ui-btn-corner-all {
   border-radius: 0m;
}
```

Comment: @Vedthanks, I tried it but it didn't work for me , I need to change border radius for this button only so i have tried : #save.ui-btn-corner-all {
   border-radius: 1m;
}  but it didn't work

Comment: ,I am using jQuery mobile 1.4.0 , Can you help me more please ?

Comment: .center_BTN .ui-btn-corner-all { border-radius: 0em; } use this . I have tested it works, 1em for rounded rectangle and 0em for rectangle shape.

Comment: @VedIts not working also !!, you have tested it on jQuery mobile 1.4.0 and on input type button ??

Comment: Open your page in browser and right click on button, and inspect with element and try to add ui-btn corner radius rubtime.